# How to display grouped products in a list with quantity in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the way grouped products are shown by two different versions of wordpress.

case 1: Wordpress 4.1.5 running WooCommerce 2.3.11 with custom theme.

[image]

case 2: Wordpress 4.2.2 running WooCommerce 2.3.11 with default theme.

[image]

I need to display grouped products (child products) in a tabular form with quantity box before it just like image2. Where do i need to make a change so i could achieve same in case 1? Why it is showing View all Products button instead of listing the products itself?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please put photos in your question instead of linking to them.

Comment: I am new to stakeoverflow and adding pics to the post requires reputation 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about WooCommerce's [template overrides](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/). If you aren't seeing the default with your theme that means that your theme is overriding it.

I can't be sure, but probably you need to go into your theme's `woocommerce` folder.... and find the `grouped.php` template in:

`yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/grouped.php`

and rename it to anything else `grouped-backup.php` so that WooCommerce will stop using it.

If that doesn't work, then it is perhaps being hidden by CSS or by Javascript. I don't have enoug information to know and you should contact your theme's author.

Comment: In my case it was the template override case, in my case it was the 

    /woocommerce/content-single-product.php

I simply reverted it back with original source and things started working perfectly.